# Laravel float variable changing value when adding to database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, latitude-longitude

**Theory**

I have quite a comprehensive coordinates list (Latitude and Longitude to 7 decimal places), which I want to continually add to. In order to stop data duplication, for each coordinate that's trying to be be inputted, I want to check the database to see if the latitude and longitude exist, on the same row.

**Check to see if coordinates exist**

```
 $coordinate = DB::table('coordinates')
            ->where('lat', '=', $geocode->getLatitude())
            ->where('lng', '=', $geocode->getLongitude())
            ->count();
```

**Migration**

```
Schema::create('coordinates', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->float('lat', 10, 7);
            $table->float('lng', 10, 7);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

When the user's address is converted, I have noticed that when `dd()` the latitude variable, it comes out as:

`float(53.7960957)` from the code `dd($geocode->getLatitude());`

When I try to add it afterwards to the database, by removing the `dd()`, the actual decimal that's added into the database is `53.7960968` - A completely different location when we're talking about coordinates!

Why is the decimal changing from echoing on my screen, to adding to the database?

Do I need to convert it to a float before adding? How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:**

I haven't used MySQL in a while, so I did some more research.  It looks like the [`decimal` type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html) has the ability to be precise for up to 65 digits.  Since you only need 7 digits passed the decimal and 3 before the decimal, you should have no problem creating a schema with `decimal(10,7)`.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1115f/1)

---

Assuming you are using MySQL, there is not much you can do.  According to [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/floating-point-types.html), `float` and `double` types are approximate representations:

> The FLOAT and DOUBLE types represent approximate numeric data values. MySQL uses four bytes for single-precision values and eight bytes for double-precision values.

Also check out this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc9cd/1), you'll see that MySQL 5.5.32 will represent a float of `53.7960957` as `53.796100616455` and a double of `53.7960957` as `53.7960957`.  You may want to update your schema to use doubles instead, for slightly more precision.

You can also specify the precision of a float with nonstandard syntax (so it is not recommended, for portability to other SQL standards) by using `float(m,d)` where `m` is the total digits and `d` is the number of digits after the decimal.  For instance, if you want to allow latitude/longitude values (-180 to 180) with up to 7 digits of precision after the decimal..you should be able to create your table with `float(10,7)`.  But, [as you'll see](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f2fe0/1), this still wasn't as precise as double was.

Comment: MySQL's reference on [Problems with Floating-Point Values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-float.html) is worth a read as well.

Comment: @Svengali see my final update. Turns out `decimal` can be precise for up to 65 digits, and you only need 10.

Answer (score 2):

as the forewriter say's ... use DOUBLE instad of FLOAT ...

you could also use 1E6 notation so it would be an Integer to save is MySQL.

```
53.7960957 * 1E6 = 537960957
537960957 / 1E6 = 53.7960957
```

this is the way I am using to save geocoordinates